# Problem with updating CyanogenMod - Phone will no finish booting up

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, custom-roms, boot, htc-evo

**TL;DR** Updated CyanogenMOD with ROM Manager and when it rebooted it is stuck on this screen:

[image: CM boot screen]

I have an EVO with cyanogen 7. The ROM Manager app notified me of of an update. I clicked through everything to proceed with the update and everything seemed to be going fine; it shutdown, started back up, then showed a screen with a lot of text and an Installation Progress bar. Once that finished, it rebooted, showing the initial white EVO 4G screen. It then goes the screen above where it has been stuck for more then half hour (the blue arrow is still circling in the circle).

Does anyone have any suggestions on what went wrong and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: Presumably you've tried rebooting again?

Comment: Yeah, I pulled the battery and it did the same thing. I tried to hold the power button down to get to the bootscreen(?) so I could try recovery mode, but nothing changed.

Comment: You probably have to hold Power + one of the volume keys for a few seconds.  If you can get into recovery, try a factory reset.

Answer (score 5):

Ok so I found the solution. It was stuck in a bootloop. [Instructions can be found here.](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/index.php?title=Troubleshooting#Problems_flashing_using_rom_manager_.28not_phone_specific.29)

**Bootloop problem**

1. Pull your battery ( If you're already in your recovery skip to step 3)
2. Use your hardware buttons to boot your phone into amon-ra or clockwork recovery (google to find out how if you're unsure)
3. Use your hardware buttons to boot your phone into amon-ra or clockwork recovery (google to find out how if you're unsure)
4. Download your rom (update-XX.zip) onto your pc - this will probably still be on your SD card
5. Place the rom (update-XX.zip) on the root of your SD card. This can be done through your recovery by selecting "mounts and storage" from the "home" menu of the recovery. Then selecting "mount USB storage"
6. From recovery select "install zip from SD card" Select it by pressing your trackball/ action button
7. Select "Choose zip from SD card" (this may vary depending on the recovery used)
8. Select it by pressing the trackball/action button
9. Locate the rom (update-XX.zip) you placed on the root of your SD. Select it by pressing the trackball/action button, confirm your selection.
10. After the install is completed successfully, hit the back button to the "home" menu of your recovery
11. Choose "Wipe data/factory reset" Select it with the trackball/action button, confirm your selection.
12. Once the wipe is complete. Use the menu to reboot your device.

YOU WILL NEED TO REINSTALL THE GOOGLE APPS SUITE (MARKET ECT)

Comment: Any way to distill the information here into your answer? If that link ever goes away your answer is absolutely useless.

Comment: Yes, good point.