# s3 bootloop switching to cyanogenmod with cwm

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-3, boot-loop

As i managed to mess up, I need your help!
I wanted to switch from samsung s3standard 4.3  to cyanogenmod11nightly:

What I did:

- with odin flashed `CF-Auto-Root-m0-m0xx-gti9300.tar.md5` to get root
- backed up data,apps,efs (no nandroid, didnt know at which point that would be done)
- because I could find out ho to get the `cm-11-20140121-NIGHTLY-i9300.zip` to install without a custom recovery, I
- reflashed `philz_touch_6.07.9-i9300.tar.md5`
- deleted everything (data/factory reset, then "clean for new ROM", cache, dalvik)
- went to `Install from .zip` -> SD Card -> no CM11 zip file there anymore!! I put it directly in the root of the sdcard

=> now bootloop. In the recovery I see only the standard folders, no usefull .zip

How do I get the CM11 zip again on the phone (or show it up if it is still there)?? And where exactly do i have to put it this time, as my "just in the root" option seemed bad.

I tried this
[Problem with updating CyanogenMod - Phone will no finish booting up](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7838/problem-with-updating-cyanogenmod-phone-will-no-finish-booting-up/7839#7839)
but i cant get the ZIP to the phone, its not recognised in Windows as Phone/Folder =(

What is the next step before I brick everything?

Comment: If you've flashed a recovery (CWM) then you've done the risky bit; I can't see how you'd brick the phone now, so follow Izzy's advice and relax!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your device supports an external microSD card: take that card, put it into a card-reader (if you don't have one: now's the time to buy it; they come for less than 10 bucks), attach the reader to your PC. Now, copy the file to the root of the card, **safely unmount**, then put the card back into your phone. You should be able to flash it then.

For what possibly happened: you might have placed the file in the root of the *internal* SDCard. Recovery is looking on the *external* card.

Comment: Thank you, worked great! =) I thought external sd cards can not be mounted.

Comment: Glad it helped! And yes: all storage can be mounted. Question is just "where" :) And issues like yours are why I'd never buy a device without *external* card support. Try a similar fix with a Nexus (no way).

Comment: Just if someone steps into the same problem: A friend told me there is also an other way with "sideload", but didnt used it as my problem was already solve with izzys advice!

Comment: That's correct: you can use `adb sideload` to update your device (see the [CWM/TWRP ADB Sideload Guide on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2559200) for the S3 Mini).